# Alias for the results of the INNER JOIN and for both tables that are being joined at the same time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, inner-join, sql-insert

```
USE [MasterDB]

GO
CREATE proc  dbo.ProductPropertiesInsert
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [MasterDB].[Main].[Property]
SELECT vp.Product_ID, vp.Property_ID
FROM ( SELECT * FROM [MasterDB].[Product].[Report] vr INNER JOIN [MasterDB].[Main].[Product] jt ON vr.vin=v.VIN )
     cross apply (values (208, jt.id, jt.IsExclusive), 
                         (209, jt.id, jt.IsNew),
                         (213, jt.id, jt.IsPremium)) 
                         vp(Property_ID, Product_ID, property)
WHERE vp.property=1
      /* optional code? */
      and not exists(select 1 
                     from [HGregoireCentral].[Main].[Property] p_in
                     where vp.id=p_in.id
                           and vp.Property_ID=p.Property_ID);
GO
```

I have this stored procedure, but I am wondering if the alias for jt is the alias for the inner join or the alias for [MasterDB].[Main].[Product].

I join it on vr.vin=v.VIN, and v stands for [MasterDB].[Main].[Product], but because v isn't defined and I need the inner join for the cross apply statement, I am not sure how to do it correctly. As of now, I think the statement wouldn't work, because I need an alias for the result of the inner join and the table [MasterDB].[Main].[Product].

How do you do this?

Report Table

```
vin isNew isExclusive isPremium 
11   1       1          0  
12   0       0          1 
13   1       0          1
```

Main Table (used for getting the property id of the property table)

```
vin id 
11  10 
12  11 
13  12
```

Property Table (I need to insert rows for each propertyId from the first table)

```
id propertyId 
10 1 
10 2 
11 3 
12 1 
12 3
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: What is your question? PS What do you mean, "alias for"? Do you mean, does jt alias the result of evaluating the inner join or just its right argument? The latter. But why would it be the former & why wouldn't it be the latter? If you don't give your reasoning, we can't find your misconceptions & you are just asking for a rewrite of an intro/manual, which is too broad & a duplicate. But if that's your question, research & ask it, don't give all this code. And ask re unexpected results before your overall goal. You mix a bunch of questions here, ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure that your query is valid SQL Server code:

- the subquery in the `from` clause is not aliases
- `jt` is defined in a subquery, and should not be available in the outer query.

But basically, I think you don't need that subquery at all. You could just flatten the joins, like:

```
INSERT INTO [MasterDB].[Main].[Property]
SELECT vp.Product_ID, vp.Property_ID
FROM [MasterDB].[Product].[Report] vr 
INNER JOIN [MasterDB].[Main].[Product] jt ON jt.vin = vr.VIN
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
    (208, jt.id, jt.IsExclusive), 
    (209, jt.id, jt.IsNew),
    (213, jt.id, jt.IsPremium)
) vp(Property_ID, Product_ID, property)
WHERE 
    vp.property=1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM [HGregoireCentral].[Main].[Property] p_in
        WHERE vp.id = p_in.id AND vp.Property_ID = p_in.Property_ID
    )
```

Note that I also fixed the incorrect table alias `p` in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery - presumably, you meant `p_in` instead. Same goes for alias `v` in the `join`.

Comment: Where does the v come from?

Comment: @deliguy: ah yes, good point, I didn’t spot this one in your query. I (tried to) fix that as well.

Comment: Also, why did you think that the code I posted was not valid mssql code? Are you saying you don't think the code you posted would run, because I don't see a lot of differences.

Comment: @deliguy: why I am suspicious about your code is explained in the answer, along with the rationale for the modified code.